# How can I sort list by second element without using lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

```
def rearrangelist(list):
    lst = input["list"]
    lst = ['list'[0]:1,'list'[1]:0,'list'[2]:3];
    print (sorted(list))
```

How can I make this work without using lambda, once I basically want the list elements to be rearrange according to the number that each list element gets defined, per example:

```
list = [john, peter, olive]
john[2], peter [1] and olive[0]
```

And I want this to be sorted according to the number printing this:

```
olive, peter, john
```

Can´t use "Zip()" function

Comment: If you don't want to use an anonymous function - name it something.

Comment: Why the restriction to not use lambda?

Comment: Your examples make no sense. Can you post proper code and data examples?

Comment: This restrictions are made by my High School teacher.

Comment: @rockethon Put that in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**decorate-sort-undecorate idiom**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate):

```
>>> names = ['john', 'peter', 'olive']
>>> order = [2, 1, 0]

>>> decorated = zip(order, names)
>>> decorated
[(2, 'john'), (1, 'peter'), (0, 'olive')]

>>> sorted_decorated = sorted(decorated)
>>> sorted_decorated
[(0, 'olive'), (1, 'peter'), (2, 'john')]

>>> undecorated = zip(*sorted_decorated)[1]
>>> undecorated
('olive', 'peter', 'john')
```

If you can't use zip:

```
>>> decorated = [(order[index], names[index]) for index in range(len(order))]
```

And:

```
>>> undecorated = [value[1] for value in decorated_sorted]
```

Comment: Can´t use zip either, sorry

Comment: I don't have Python3.5. In what way doesn't it work? Which line? What error?

Comment: Line 5 :  undecorated = zip(*sorted_decorated)[1]
TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @rockethon Ah! In Python 3 `zip` is a generator object. Python 2 creates a list. Python 3 you'd have to do `list(zip(*sorted_decorated))[1]`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use the `operator.itemgetter` function

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(sorted(list, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

By the way, `list` is a terrible name for a variable, as it will shadow the list type.

Comment: I just gave that name for example proposes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> **sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])**
>   Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.
>
> The optional arguments cmp, key, and reverse have the same meaning as those for the list.sort() method.
>
> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

`key` is what you need. Supply it a function that will return a comparison key

```
def SortBySecondElement(Element):
    return Element[1]
```

Call sorted method this way

```
sorted(list, key=SortBySecondElement)
```

I hope that is what you want.

Comment: Instead of defining your own function you could use `itemgetter` in `operator module`: sorted(list, key=operator.itemgetter(1))

Comment: @mnencia You're right and this solution is more concise than the one I've provided.